# swift 2 popup tableView when search

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I am working with a library application. User can search book in the app by entering keyword.

The question is the searchSuggestion_tableView will be only displayed when the searchBar activated. When finish searching, the searchSuggestion_tableView will be hidden, then the result_tableview will display the detail of the book.

However, i don't know how to do it in ios 9. i found some tutorials in ios 7.

**---------------------PhotoShop :)--------------------------**

First, i have 2 arrays in the swift file

```
 let bookName = ["iPad User Guide for iOS 9.2", "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2 Prerelease)", "MacBook Pro Essentials", "Othello"]

 let Author =["Apple Inc.", "William Shakespeare"]
```

**before searching**

[image: before searching]

**When searching**

[image: When searching]

**Click the suggestion**

[image: Click the suggestion]

Comment: any idea or any tutorial suggest?

Comment: Use predicate to search data from your arrays . then show it in sectional tableview . and on selection reload the previous table view or show a new tableview with selected data .

Comment: ok, I find my problems. i don't know how to show 2 UITableViews in one screen. Also, i don't know how to handle the event when something is clicked on the TableView(the searchSuggestion_tableView).